# Porque mis botones desaparecen?

Tags: html, nodejs, ionic, ionic4

Tengo mi programa ionic y electron, que sirve como un control remoto que controla proyectores, bocinas, etc. Donde genero un componente botón, este componente botón, tiene distinta información que va ligada a una lista de acciones que está en un proceder, esto para que se cargue al iniciar la aplicación, también al llamar el proveer hace la llamada de la información sobre que botones se van a mostrar a un backend que yo tengo, llama la información y la guarda en la variable que está en el providers, el tema es que pareciera ser que la variable donde se ubica la información pareciera ser que la elimina después de cierto evento que desconozco, ha habido ya 3 momentos en los que sucedió este caso.

```
export class BotonesProvider{

    botones_usados: any
    dispositivo_actual: any

    constructor(public http: Http, public storage: Storage) {
            this.getBotonesUsados()
            this.storage.get('dispositivo').then(data => {
                    this.dispositivo_actual= data
            })
    }
...
    getBotonesUsados() {
            this.http.get(API + "/api/getBotones")
            .map(res => res.json())
            .subscribe(data => {
                this.botones_usados= data
             });
     }
}
```

La variable que muestra los botones es la que dice `botones_usados` y se carga en `getBotonesUsados()` y en otros dispositivos se me ha funcionado y en los dispositivos que generaron problemas ya no se pudo replicar el problema.

En mi HTML solo lo mando a llamar asi:

```
<div *ngFor="let asistencia of asistenciasProvider.asistencias" col-6 zcol-sm-4 col-md-3 col-lg-3 col-xl-3>
...
<div>
```

Estoy usando Ionic 4, pareciera que está perdiendo referencia a memoria, pero no entiendo como o porque. ¿Tienen alguna idea? Gracias